# Def variable with "string" XML in Karate

Tags: xml, karate

My question its similar to another existing one (sorry about that) but with something difference... my XML input has string format:

```
* def token = '123456'
* def payload =
"""
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:isValid>
         &lt;token&gt;#(token)&lt;/token&gt;
      </ws:isValid>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""
* print payload
```

Which prints:

```
[print] <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.com">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ws:isValid>
       &lt;token&gt;#(token)&lt;/token&gt;
    </ws:isValid>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can you help me please?

---

I tried with the given solution but doesnt work either:

```
def num = '&lt;num&gt;' + random_num(5) + '&lt;/num&gt;'
[print] &lt;num&gt;39631&lt;/num&gt;

Given request:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <ns1>
        <ns1:XML_INPUT>     
    &lt;testone&gt;00&lt;/testone&gt;    
    &lt;numtwo&gt;267&lt;/testtwo&gt;   
    #(num)
    &lt;testthree&gt;267&lt;/testthree&gt;
        </ns1:XML_INPUT>
    </ns1>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you know that there is a possible duplicate it is useful to add a link and not just mention the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
* def token = '&lt;token&gt;' + 123456 + '&lt;/token&gt;'
* def payload =
"""
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:isValid>#(token)</ws:isValid>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""
```

And read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

Comment: Thanks Mr. Thomas. I tried the given solution but doesnt work either, i've posted the request in the post above. Can you help me please?

Comment: @Cherryhoney sorry I can't help with this invalid XML. please just use a string replace. search the docs or other answers on stack overflow